# How do you disconnect from a camera using Flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, camera

I have a flash application that connects to a users webcam using

```
public static function getCamera(name:String = null):Camera
```

When the application is done with the use of the webcam it needs to be disconnected since its making use of resources unnecessarily.How can I do this?

Apologies for being a "micro-efficiency" freak. I am not even sure how inefficient it is, but I don't like the idea of the camera being just connected when not used.

I have checked the API and have found no function to do that.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483277/close-webcam-usage-via-actionscript also remove the cam from the video display by attaching null to the display.
video.attachCamera(cam);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call on you [NetStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/net/NetStream.html#attachCamera%28%29):

```
attachCamera(null);
```