# Close webcam usage via actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, camera, webcam

Is there way, how to close webcam connection in actionscript. I am opening stream through Camera.getCamera(). Problem is, that after freeing webcam instance (i tried many ways) LIGHT on webcam is still beam (tried on macbook pro).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call `video.attachCamera(null)` to free the camera.

The below example demonstrates the code. When you click on the stage, Camera is toggled on/off.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;

    public class testAS3 extends Sprite
    {
        public var cam:Camera;
        public var video:Video;
        public var camOn:Boolean = false;


        public function testAS3()
        {
            cam = Camera.getCamera();
            video = new Video();
            addChild(video);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleCamera);
        }

        public function toggleCamera(evt:Event):void {
            if (camOn){
                video.attachCamera(null);
            } else {
                video.attachCamera(cam);
            }

            camOn = !camOn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will it release the camera if i do video=null, without calling attachCamera(null)