# Unable to free my webcam in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, webcam

To free my webcam I'm using

```
onScrenVideo.attachCamera(null)
```

where `onScreenVideo` is a `Video` object.

However, this just doesn't seem to work. Even after this line executes, the webcam light remains ON.

I have scoured the Internet for a solution to this problem and everyone seems to be unanimous that this is the only way to turn the webcam off (for example : [Close webcam usage via actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483277/close-webcam-usage-via-actionscript)), however, this just doesn't seem to be working for me.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

**Edit:** Adding relevant code.

All the variables are declared previously. Here's the code to set up the Camera and attach it to the video.

```
testCurrCam = Camera.getCamera();
onScreenVideo = new Video(240, 180);
onScreenVideo.smoothing = true;
onScreenVideo.x = 0;
onScreenVideo.y = 0;
addChild(onScreenVideo);
testCurrCam.setQuality(0, 70);
testCurrCam.setMode(640, 480, 10);
onScreenVideo.attachCamera(testCurrCam);
```

And here's a function which is called by Javascript using `ExternalInterface`. The call works perfectly fine, because I've checked using an alert box after the `if` condition.

```
private function stopCam(): void {  
     if (contains(onScreenVideo)) {       
          onScreenVideo.attachCamera(null);
          this.removeChild(onScreenVideo);
          onScreenVideo = null;
          testCurrCam = null;
       }   else
             return;
}
```

Comment: Is there another object, like a NetStream, that you have the camera attached to?  You haven't set up an event listener for the camera's videoFrame event?  (Just guessing on the latter, I've not tried myself to see if that keeps the camera turned on)

Comment: There isn't any netstream in this case. It is just meant to display live video. Do I need an event handler for this as well?

Comment: I believe Bill was just trying to assess whether you had any other remaining references to the camera that would keep it from shutting down. Having said that, it may help for you to post all the code pertaining to your camera and video instances.

Comment: I've added the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Marcella, that was my intent.  wrahool, the event handler isn't needed, I was just wondering if perhaps it was keeping the camera active.  The code you posted looks correct.  The only time I've seen the camera stay live is if there is some other object that is still using it, hence the questions I asked.